# Mobile debugging wondering about performance

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4, flex4.5

I am debugging an app I am creating on an ipad. The app is so slow that I am a little bit ashamed to show it to the customers. So far since it is just debugging I am thinking that this is probably the reason. What I am really wondering is will this be the same when I distribute? Can someone explain what is the performance difference between a debugged app and a distributed one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing a "Fast Compile" version of your app?  Or are you creating a formal release version?  What aspects of your application are slow?  Flex is not known for 'speed' on mobile for various reasons.  It is usually "good enough" for a business app; but probably  not for a game board.  I really think you need to get into more specifics as to what problems you're experiencing.

Comment: As @Reboog711 mentioned, it depends on what exactly you are looking at. There are four ways to compile for iOS: Fast Debug, Standard Debug, Ad Hoc release, and App Store release. Ad Hoc and App Store are the same, just signed differently. Fast is quick to compile, but **extremely** slow on device. We're talking a max of 10fps for *any* app. Standard debug takes about as long as a full release to compile, but is still only about 75% as fast on-device. We really need more info in order to help beyond that.

Comment: Most likely the problem which you have is not related to debugging. It's important to keep eye on better performance approaches during working on mobile applications with flex.
If you have lists I suggest you to rewrite itemrenderers in plain actionscript, or at least remove bindings.

Comment: @DaniilMoskovtsov The debug / fast packaged versions of a AIR Mobile app are known to have much worse performance than a release version. Adobe makes a concessions in order to speed up packaging. It could very well be a factor in the performance Dave is seeing.

Comment: We would really have to see large chunks of your code to audit it.  You may want to profile your application to see where your time is being spent.  Of course, the usual suspects in Flex/AIR optimization are always there.  Use Vectors over Arrays and Arrays over ArrayCollections whenever possible.  Use AS classes over MXML classes whenever possible. Don't use databinding when it isn't necessary.  Don't loop over Arrays/Vectors/ArrayCollection to see if your app has received an object, use a Dictionary instead.